# Using buffers and streams to write the data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stream, buffer

I need a **node.js** program for the following 
I have an huge JSON data which have an thousands of records I need to copy to the another file using streams. But there are 3 key value pairs but i need to  copy only the one key value (i.e.) I have `name`, `age` and `city`, but I need in another file only the names of the json record .

Can you suggest me if there are any alternatives. Also the file size is too big consists of thousands of records.

sample data taken as

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"John",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"vamsi",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"loga",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"krishna",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"kishore",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"reddy",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   }
]
```

Comment: If the data is properly formatted in a line by line manner as shown in the example, you can use `readline` module from the nodejs builtin modules to read the json line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy using streams:

First install some modules for streaming JSON and transformation

```
npm install --save JSONStream scramjet
```

Then write the code:

```
const scramjet = require("scramjet");
const fs = require("fs");
const JSONStream = require("JSONStream")

fs.createReadStream(filename)             // open the file
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))          // parse JSON array to object stream
    .pipe(new scramjet.DataStream)        // pipe for transformation
    .map(({name}) => name)                 // extract "name" field from each object
    .toJSONArray()                        // create an array stream
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outname)); // write to output.
```

See the docs for more info:

- [JSON Stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream)
- [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet)
- [Node.js Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply but the code is not working .map(({name} => name))                 // extract "name" field from each object
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Try now. There was a parenthesis missing